# Rewind back - not just $.mobile.changePage

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

History of my pages / activities is:

1. Home page (page0).
2. List of issues (page1).
3. Detail card of issue (page2).
4. Popup for confirmation to delete issue (not a page because of JQM popup isn't a page).

When I confirm deletion of issue and delete it, there is no reason to return back to page2 (it's content dropped). The only valid transition here - from popup to list of issues (back twice).

BUT.
When I jump from popup to page1 by `$.mobile.changePage`, history saves page2 as previous page (because jump was started at page2' popup).
So, when I press back on page1 I expect to return on page0 (rewind history), but returns to page2 which is invalid.
Guess valid behaviour here is:

1. Jump from popup to page1.
2. Erase page2 and popup from history at all - or something similar.

How to do it?

Comment: Any ideas?
I found that answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206108/how-to-navigate-back-one-page-using-mobile-changepage?rq=1 can't help me

Comment: have you tried history.go(-2) ? try that on click event of back button

Comment: Hello, Najeeb.
Yes' it's working, thanks a lot